# Converting logical from CNF to DNF and Vice Versa?

Tags: boolean, logic

i am in a discrete math class and would like some help. This is what i have so far:

```
~ = not
| = or
& = and

So convert (X|Y) & (Z|~P) to DNF
-I got (X&Y) | (Z&~P)
Convert (X&Y) | (Z&P) to CNF         
-I got (X|Z) & (Y|Z) & (X|P) & (Y|P)
```

Are these correct?

Comment: Wolfram alpha is good for checking, but if you want to get a deeper understanding it might help to draw up a truth table with the 16 cases, then check your CNF or DNF to see it gives the same results as your original statement.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. x and y do not both have to be true, so your DNF is not right. You can check these on Wolfram Alpha with DNF ((x || y) && (Z || ~P)) and it will tell you all 4 ways this could be true, connected by ors. (so x and z, x and not p, y and z, y and not p). For CNF, you need not P where you have P. Also again if you ask WolframAlpha cNF ((x || y) && (Z || ~P)) it will tell you that basically it is in CNF. Wolfram alpha also defines these terms.